# Why does clicking on the header automatically sort the table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TableTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
         {
            var frame = new PlanetTableFrame();
            frame.setTitle("TableTest");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         });
   }
}
class PlanetTableFrame extends JFrame
{
   private String[] columnNames = { "Planet", "Radius", "Moons", "Gaseous", "Color" };
   private Object[][] cells = 
   { 
      { "Mercury", 2440.0, 0, false, Color.YELLOW },
      { "Venus", 6052.0, 0, false, Color.YELLOW }, 
      { "Earth", 6378.0, 1, false, Color.BLUE },
      { "Mars", 3397.0, 2, false, Color.RED }, 
      { "Jupiter", 71492.0, 16, true, Color.ORANGE },
      { "Saturn", 60268.0, 18, true, Color.ORANGE },
      { "Uranus", 25559.0, 17, true, Color.BLUE }, 
      { "Neptune", 24766.0, 8, true, Color.BLUE },
      { "Pluto", 1137.0, 1, false, Color.BLACK } 
   };
   public PlanetTableFrame()
   {
      var table = new JTable(cells, columnNames);
      table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
      add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }
}
```

Running the program, when I click on the column header, the rows are automatically sorted.

I want to know why: when I click the column header, what happens inside the Swing component (what method is triggered)? I just clicked the table header and did not change the model content. Why does it automatically sort?

Comment: By calling `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);` you tell the `JTable` to take all the necessary steps to enableautomatic row sorting. More details (from the user of the row sorting perspective) can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting . For all the nitty-gritty details: you will probably have to trace this in the source code yourself. IMHO this process is to complex for a simple answer.

Comment: *when I click the column header* - doesn't your question give the answer? The setAutoCreatRowSorter() method would a MouseListener to the table header to implement the sorting functionality. What is the point of this question? Why would you invoke this method if you don't want automatic sorting?

Comment: Yes, can you tell me what method of what listener will be called? I can't find the relevant implementation in the java source code.

Comment: I think the question is not clear, maybe you add some additional information to it, or try re-phrasing it - as it is now, it is not clear (since obviously the table is being sorted since a `RowSorter` gets added to it as set by `setAutoCreateRowSorter()`)

Comment: Maybe it will be clearer if I ask another question: When I click on the column header, what method will be automatically triggered?

Comment: *what method will be automatically triggered?* -  Why do you care? What problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: I don't want to solve any actual problem, I am just very curious, because I carefully checked the java source code and did not solve this doubt. I don't even know what the event source is: `JTable`, `JTableHeader`, or something else?

Comment: 1) Step through the code using the debugger of your IDE, or 2) Read the API for the DefaultRowSorter to figure out which methods you think should be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary objects that are involved in table sorting are:

- [`JTable`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JTable.java). No matter which `JTable` constructor you call the effective constructor is [`JTable(TableModel, TableColumnModel, ListSelectionModel)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JTable.java#L679)
- [`JTableHeader`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.java). An object of this class is constructed when executing [`JTable.initializeLocalVars()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/JTable.java#L5608) which is called from the `JTable` constructor
- a [`BasicTableHeaderUI`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableHeaderUI.java) is constructed in the `JTableHeader` constructor (during the call to `JTableHeader.updateUI()`)
- [`BasicTableHeaderUI.MouseInputHandler`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableHeaderUI.java#L107) which handles mouse input for the `BasicTableHeaderUI`. An instance of this class is constructed from the calls originating in `JTableHeader.updateUI()` and is added as a mouse listener to the `JTableHeader`
- [`TableRowSorter`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.java) - the `JTable` creates an instance of this class when you call `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`

The [`BasicTableHeaderUI.MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableHeaderUI.java#L117) is the method that gets called when you click in the table header.

After some checks this method calls `RowSorter.toggleSortOrder(int column)` which informs the `TableRowSorter` that it should change the sorting.

Note that sorting the table doesn't sort the table model! The `TableRowSorter` internally maintains two arrays to convert from (sorted) view row index to model row index and from model row index to (sorted) view row index.

In the unsorted state these arrays map index 0 to index 0, index 1 to index 1 etc.

When sorting these arrays are shuffled.

---

Final note: this post mentions the class `BasicTableHeaderUI`. Depending on the LAF that your application uses it could be a different class (for example the `WindowsTableHeaderUI` if your application uses the Windows LAF).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the answer I wanted, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [`JTable#setAutoCreateRowSorter(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateRowSorter-boolean-), which makes the table automatically create row sorters for each column based on the column type (see [`JTable.getColumnClass(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnClass-int-)).

If you do not want the table to sort when you click a column header, then do not call `setAutoCreateRowSorter`.

Comment: I know that calling the `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` method allows automatic sorting when clicking on the column header, but my question is why does this happen when I call the `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` method?

Comment: @KkLee Why does clicking on a button invoke the action of the button when you use the addActionListener() method of the button? How is clicking on the header any different? You invoke a method on a component to enable the related processing on the component.